# Obtengo TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, linux

```
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

neural_n = create_nn(topology, sigm)

loss = []

for i in range(1000):
    #Entrenaando la red
    pY = train(neural_n, x, y, l2_cost)

    if i % 25 == 0:

      loss.append(l2_cost[0](pY, y))

      res = 50

      _x0 = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, res)
      _x1 = np.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, res)

      _y = np.zeros((res, res))
      

      for i0, x0 in enumerate(_x0):
        for i1, x1 in enumerate(_x1):
          _y[i0, i1] = train(neural_n, np.array([[x0, x1]]), y, l2_cost, train = False)[0][0]
      plt.pcolormesh(x0, _x1, _y, cmap="coolwarm")
      plt.axis("equal")

      plt.scatter(x[y[:, 0] == 0, 0],x[y[:, 0] == 0, 1], c= "skyblue")
      plt.scatter(x[y[:, 0] == 1, 0],x[y[:, 0] == 1, 1], c= "salmon")
      
      clear_output(wait=True)
      plt.show()
      plt.plot(range(len(loss)), loss)
      plt.show()
      time.sleep(0.5)
```

El error es:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-81970648a3df> in <module>()
     24       for i0, x0 in enumerate(_x0):
     25         for i1, x1 in enumerate(_x1):
---> 26           _y[i0, i1] = train(neural_n, np.array([[x0, x1]]), y, l2_cost, train = False)[0]
     27       plt.pcolormesh(x0, _x1, _y, cmap="coolwarm")
     28       plt.axis("equal")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: la llamada a `train()` ha retornado `None` (lo que ocurre por ejemplo cuando termina sin encontrar un `return` explícito). Así que el intento de acceder a `train()[0]` es un error.

Comment: y ¿Tienes idea de como puedo corregirlo?

Comment: No, desconozco qué librerías estás usando, si la función `train` es parte de un framework o algo que tú has escrito, qué se supone que hace esa función y qué se espera que retorne, etc... Solo puedo decirte lo que se deduce del mensaje de error, para que tú puedas seguir investigando las causas. Prueba a recoger lo que devuelve `train()` en una variable temporal para imprimir luego esa variable o su tipo. Quizás en vez de `None` te está retornando un array que tiene `None` en su interior. Pero igualmente yo no sabría decirte por qué.

Comment: @JuanEduarte puedes hacer algo como: `tmp = train(neural_n, np.array([[x0, x1]]), y, l2_cost, train = False)[0]` `if tmp is not None: y[i0, i1] = tmp`